# Ansible lineinfile regexp line with spaces

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a line in a config file, to which I would like to modify the line. I use the below code

```
- name: insert line
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/config
    regexp: '^(.*)password root(.*)$'
    line: password root {{ hello }}
```

so in above case, when even i run the ansible task it just inserts a new line, but never modifies the line. How do i avoid the space of the string in the regexp ? Ive tried "\s" and "/\s" but couldnt fix it.

the output file /etc/config looks like below for example.

```
password root alpha
```

next time I run the code it becomes

```
password root beta
```

here in my case the {{ hello }} variables keeps changing so I want to replace instead of adding new line.

Comment: Maybe `'^(\S*)password root(\S*)$'`? Or, without parentheses, `'^\S*password root\S*$'`.

Comment: Nope that doesnt help, the pattern matching fails and it just adds a new line. It works when we just search with '^(.*)password (.*)$', but when we add line with spaces it wont.

Comment: can you put out the contents of /etc/config and state what are you trying to replace .

Comment: yeah I added the output

Answer (score 1):

The problem identified in this case is, since the output line (i.e in /etc/config) starts with no spaces,

```
regexp: '^password root(.*)$'
```

the regex should be as above and no need of \s to overcome space between password and root.